# Jquery selector: targeting an element with two class prefixes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some elements that contain two similar classes like "col-md-3 col-md-6" on the same element and I want to identify them with a jQuery selector.

example:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-6"></div
```

how can I select only elements that contain these two classes?

I have tried something like :

```
$("[class*='col-md-'][class*='col-md-']").css("background", "#07BCCD")
```

but is targeting all elements with one or two class prefix "`col-md-"`

**[fiddle js:](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/265/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no selector that does this kind of pattern matching. You'll need to match one of the classes, and then use `.filter()` to test whether it has at least two classes that match.

```js
$("[class^=col-md-]").filter(function() {
  return this.className.split(' ').filter(function(e) {
    return e.indexOf('col-md-') == 0;
  }).length >= 2;
}).css("background-color", "#07BCCD");
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put both classes together without space:

```
$(".col-md-3.col-md-6").css("background", "#07BCCD");
```

**UPDATE:**
You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var prefix = $("[class*='col-md-']").filter("[class*=' col-md-']").css("background", "#07BCCD");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/274/)

Comment: unfortunately all these classes are dynamically added and I must use their prefixes and not entire class. –

Comment: your solution will target all elements that have a second class with prefix "col-md-". Is not quite what I am seeking, I already know all these solutions I just need a selector that will filter all html elements that contain two classes with a similar prefix like "col-md-"

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter()` and the following logic to calculate two occurrences,

```
var prefix = $(".row div").filter(function () {
    return ($(this).attr('class').split('col-md-')).length > 2;
}).css("background", "#07BCCD");
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/ZurAk/278/)**